# Selenium Browser immediately closes after test, even when I explicitly "detach" it

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

my selenium code is detaching even when I use options. Here is my code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

link = input("Link: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\mferr\Desktop\bin\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=opts)

driver.get(link)
```

Comment: Chrome will quit when the Chromedriver session is quit.  Setting "detach" to true only makes it so that it doesn't close if the chromedriver process is killed without quitting the session.  (a crash or manual killing of process?) https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities